# WPF создание ресурса с несколькими параметрами

Tags: wpf, xaml

У меня на окне располагается 9 StackPanel, я делаю для них анимацию смены цвета при наведении мыши

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                            <ColorAnimation To="#FF153874" Duration="0:0:0:0.3"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                            <ColorAnimation To="#FF485976" Duration="0:0:0:0.3"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

У каждой панели разный цвет и соответственно менять тоже нужно разный цвет, а писать 9 раз этот код для каждой панели, ну понимаете...
Можно ли как то создать ресурс с параметрами (входным и выходным цветом)?

Comment: По идее через AttachedProperty можно, но пока мне не понятно как это сделать

Comment: пока не уверен, что понимаю, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @FoggyFinder, вроде понятно же - запускать анимацию, но чтобы конечное значение можно было задавать для каждого элемента отдельно, при этом стиль не плодить для каждого элемента, а иметь один универсальный параметризированный

Comment: @Андрей да, но мне интересно подняться на уровень выше - зачем создавать 9 StackPanel - уже похоже на какую сетку (поле).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, но неочевидным образом.

К сожалению, в анимации невозможно использовать ни `Binding`, ни `DynamicResource`, поэтому придётся пойти обходным путём.

Идея такова: будем вместо цвета анимировать число от 0.0 до 1.0 и обратно, а цвет фона вычислим из начального и конечного цветов через конвертер.

Реализуем!

Итак, для начала конвертер, который будет интерполировать цвета. Он очень простой. Идея одолжена [здесь](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/MS/Internal/AnimatedTypeHelpers.cs,25).

```
class ColorInterpolationConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        if (values.Contains(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        Color from = (Color)values[0];
        Color to =   (Color)values[1];
        double ratio = (double)values[2];
        return from + (to - from) * (float)ratio;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object p, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь, нам нужно задать начальный и конечный цвет. Это должны быть, по идее, attached property. Так же нам нужно attached property для текущего значения соотношения между начальным и конечным цветами, которое мы будем анимировать. Определяем их во вспомогательном классе:

```
static class ColorExtensions
{
    #region attached property double Ratio
    public static double GetRatio(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (double)obj.GetValue(RatioProperty);

    public static void SetRatio(DependencyObject obj, double value) =>
        obj.SetValue(RatioProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RatioProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Ratio", typeof(double), typeof(ColorExtensions));
    #endregion

    #region attached property Color BaseColor
    public static Color GetBaseColor(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (Color)obj.GetValue(BaseColorProperty);

    public static void SetBaseColor(DependencyObject obj, Color value) =>
        obj.SetValue(BaseColorProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BaseColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BaseColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorExtensions));
    #endregion

    #region attached property Color HoverColor
    public static Color GetHoverColor(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (Color)obj.GetValue(HoverColorProperty);

    public static void SetHoverColor(DependencyObject obj, Color value) =>
        obj.SetValue(HoverColorProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "HoverColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorExtensions));
    #endregion
}
```

Окей, теперь сам стиль.

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="S1">
    <!-- положим конвертер прямо в стиль -->
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:ColorInterpolationConverter x:Key="RatioToColorConverter"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <!-- привяжем цвет фона к значению ColorExtensions.Ratio через конвертер -->
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RatioToColorConverter}">
                        <!-- здесь наш текущий элемент - SolidColorBrush,
                             поэтому навигируем вверх до stack panel -->
                        <Binding Path="(local:ColorExtensions.BaseColor)"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                       AncestorType=FrameworkElement}"/>
                        <Binding Path="(local:ColorExtensions.HoverColor)"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                       AncestorType=FrameworkElement}"/>
                        <Binding Path="(local:ColorExtensions.Ratio)"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                       AncestorType=FrameworkElement}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </SolidColorBrush.Color>
            </SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <!-- на hover-событии анимируем Ratio с 0 до 1 -->
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:ColorExtensions.Ratio)">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <!-- ... и обратно -->
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:ColorExtensions.Ratio)">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0:0.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Используем:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource S1}"
            local:ColorExtensions.BaseColor="#FF153874"
            local:ColorExtensions.HoverColor="#FF485976"/>
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Кода получилось довольно много, но в принципе, его можно повторно использовать. Если бы в анимации можно было бы задавать параметры более гибко, такая сложность бы не понадобилась.